# spring hibernate sessionFactory NullPointerException

Tags: spring-mvc

Hi I'm writing an application and I'm getting the following error.

Edit: Complete log

```
`
       Aug 20, 2012 6:37:22 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin;.;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;F:\SVN\bin\;F:\SVN\Python25\;C:\Program Files\PHP\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin;D:\apache-ant-1.8.2\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin;C:\Program Files\QuickTime\QTSystem\
Aug 20, 2012 6:37:22 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:yogamandir1' did not find a matching property.
Aug 20, 2012 6:37:22 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Aug 20, 2012 6:37:23 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Aug 20, 2012 6:37:23 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1277 ms
Aug 20, 2012 6:37:23 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Aug 20, 2012 6:37:23 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.8
Aug 20, 2012 6:37:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/core_rt is already defined
Aug 20, 2012 6:37:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/core is already defined
Aug 20, 2012 6:37:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core is already defined
Aug 20, 2012 6:37:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt_rt is already defined
Aug 20, 2012 6:37:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt is already defined
Aug 20, 2012 6:37:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt is already defined
Aug 20, 2012 6:37:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions is already defined
Aug 20, 2012 6:37:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://jakarta.apache.org/taglibs/standard/permittedTaglibs is already defined
Aug 20, 2012 6:37:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://jakarta.apache.org/taglibs/standard/scriptfree is already defined
Aug 20, 2012 6:37:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/sql_rt is already defined
Aug 20, 2012 6:37:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/sql is already defined
Aug 20, 2012 6:37:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql is already defined
Aug 20, 2012 6:37:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/xml_rt is already defined
Aug 20, 2012 6:37:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/xml is already defined
Aug 20, 2012 6:37:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/xml is already defined
Aug 20, 2012 6:37:27 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext - Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Mon Aug 20 18:37:28 IST 2012]; root of context hierarchy
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml]
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@d9ceea: defining beans []; root of factory hierarchy
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 582 ms
Aug 20, 2012 6:37:28 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'appServlet'
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - FrameworkServlet 'appServlet': initialization started
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext - Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'appServlet-servlet': startup date [Mon Aug 20 18:37:28 IST 2012]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml]
INFO : org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner - JSR-330 'javax.inject.Named' annotation found and supported for component scanning
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer - Loading properties file from class path resource [jdbc.properties]
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor - JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@659078: defining beans [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping#0,org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.MappedInterceptor#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.ResponseStatusExceptionResolver#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter,org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver#0,studentDAO,homeController,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping#1,org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean#1,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter#1,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.MappedInterceptor#1,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver#1,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.ResponseStatusExceptionResolver#1,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver#1,org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer#0,dataSource,sessionFactory,transactionManager,multipartResolver,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0,org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0,org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor$ImportAwareBeanPostProcessor#0]; parent: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@d9ceea
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/register],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String com.omkar.yogamandir.web.controllers.HomeController.register(java.util.Locale,org.springframework.ui.Model,com.omkar.yogamandir.web.beans.Student,org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile,org.springframework.validation.BindingResult)
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String com.omkar.yogamandir.web.controllers.HomeController.home(java.util.Locale,org.springframework.ui.Model)
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/resources/**] onto handler 'org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler#0'
INFO : org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource - Loaded JDBC driver: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
INFO : org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.Version - Hibernate Annotations 3.3.1.GA
INFO : org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - Hibernate 3.2.6
INFO : org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - hibernate.properties not found
INFO : org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - Bytecode provider name : cglib
INFO : org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - using JDK 1.4 java.sql.Timestamp handling
INFO : org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder - Binding entity from annotated class: com.omkar.yogamandir.entity.beans.BatchDTO
INFO : org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder - Bind entity com.omkar.yogamandir.entity.beans.BatchDTO on table batch
INFO : org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder - Binding entity from annotated class: com.omkar.yogamandir.entity.beans.StudentDTO
INFO : org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder - Bind entity com.omkar.yogamandir.entity.beans.StudentDTO on table student
INFO : org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration - Hibernate Validator not found: ignoring
INFO : org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean - Building new Hibernate SessionFactory
INFO : org.hibernate.connection.ConnectionProviderFactory - Initializing connection provider: org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider
INFO : org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - RDBMS: MySQL, version: 5.5.8
INFO : org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - JDBC driver: MySQL-AB JDBC Driver, version: mysql-connector-java-5.1.15 ( Revision: ${bzr.revision-id} )
INFO : org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect - Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
INFO : org.hibernate.transaction.TransactionFactoryFactory - Transaction strategy: org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SpringTransactionFactory
INFO : org.hibernate.transaction.TransactionManagerLookupFactory - No TransactionManagerLookup configured (in JTA environment, use of read-write or transactional second-level cache is not recommended)
INFO : org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Automatic flush during beforeCompletion(): disabled
INFO : org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Automatic session close at end of transaction: disabled
INFO : org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - JDBC batch size: 15
INFO : org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - JDBC batch updates for versioned data: disabled
INFO : org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Scrollable result sets: enabled
INFO : org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - JDBC3 getGeneratedKeys(): enabled
INFO : org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Connection release mode: auto
INFO : org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Maximum outer join fetch depth: 2
INFO : org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Default batch fetch size: 1
INFO : org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Generate SQL with comments: disabled
INFO : org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Order SQL updates by primary key: disabled
INFO : org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Order SQL inserts for batching: disabled
INFO : org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Query translator: org.hibernate.hql.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
INFO : org.hibernate.hql.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory - Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
INFO : org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Query language substitutions: {}
INFO : org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - JPA-QL strict compliance: disabled
INFO : org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Second-level cache: enabled
INFO : org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Query cache: disabled
INFO : org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Cache provider: org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider
INFO : org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Optimize cache for minimal puts: disabled
INFO : org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Structured second-level cache entries: disabled
INFO : org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Echoing all SQL to stdout
INFO : org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Statistics: disabled
INFO : org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Deleted entity synthetic identifier rollback: disabled
INFO : org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Default entity-mode: pojo
INFO : org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Named query checking : enabled
INFO : org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl - building session factory
INFO : org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryObjectFactory - Not binding factory to JNDI, no JNDI name configured
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/register],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String com.omkar.yogamandir.web.controllers.HomeController.register(java.util.Locale,org.springframework.ui.Model,com.omkar.yogamandir.web.beans.Student,org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile,org.springframework.validation.BindingResult)
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String com.omkar.yogamandir.web.controllers.HomeController.home(java.util.Locale,org.springframework.ui.Model)
INFO : org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager - Using DataSource [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource@89eb77] of Hibernate SessionFactory for HibernateTransactionManager
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - FrameworkServlet 'appServlet': initialization completed in 6021 ms
Aug 20, 2012 6:37:34 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Aug 20, 2012 6:37:34 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Aug 20, 2012 6:37:34 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 11556 ms
INFO : com.omkar.yogamandir.web.controllers.HomeController - Welcome home! the client locale is en_US
INFO : com.omkar.yogamandir.web.controllers.HomeController - Welcome home! the client locale is en_US
INFO : com.omkar.yogamandir.web.controllers.HomeController - Student Registration!
INFO : com.omkar.yogamandir.entity.dao.StudentDAO - Start: saveStudent() in StudentDAO class
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.omkar.yogamandir.entity.dao.StudentDAO.saveStudent(StudentDAO.java:27)
    at com.omkar.yogamandir.business.StudentBusinessAdapter.insertStudent(StudentBusinessAdapter.java:30)
    at com.omkar.yogamandir.web.controllers.HomeController.register(HomeController.java:59)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:213)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:96)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:617)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:578)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:306)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:541)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:383)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:243)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:288)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

`

My StudentDAO class:

```
`package com.omkar.yogamandir.entity.dao;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.omkar.yogamandir.entity.beans.StudentDTO;

@Repository
@Transactional
public class StudentDAO {

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory
        .getLogger(StudentDAO.class);

@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

public void saveStudent(StudentDTO studentDTO) {

    try{
        logger.info("Start: saveStudent() in StudentDAO class");
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        session.save(studentDTO);
        logger.info("Successfully saved the student!!!");
    } catch(Exception e){

        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
}`
```

servlet-context.xml

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc     http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx     http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

<!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing 
    infrastructure -->

<!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
<annotation-driven />

<!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving 
    up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

<!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources 
    in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
<beans:bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</beans:bean>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.omkar.yogamandir" />

<annotation-driven />

<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:jdbc.properties"></context:property-placeholder>


<beans:bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
    <beans:property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
    <beans:property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
    <beans:property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></beans:property>
    <beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
        <beans:props>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</beans:prop>
        </beans:props>
    </beans:property>
    <beans:property name="packagesToScan" value="com.omkar.yogamandir"></beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="multipartResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
    <beans:property name="maxUploadSize" value="5000000" />
</beans:bean>

<tx:annotation-driven />

</beans:beans>`
```

I have all the required jars in classpath. Please have a look at this issue.
sessionFactory is null when I use sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

Comment: is your `jdbc.properties` on the classpath, is the information inside correct? what about server startup log. You should see issues in there while creating sesssionFactory bean

Comment: yes, jdbc.properties is on classpath and has correct information. it was missing previously and would throw an error. I've added the complete log now. Please have a look at it. Thanks!

Comment: I made the studentDAO.saveStudent() call from the controller directly and it started working. What happens when I introduce another layer??can anyone pls explain?

Comment: @Vijay You didn't post your controller code. Are you by any chance calling `new StudentDAO()`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is my Spring @Autowired field null?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19896870/why-is-my-spring-autowired-field-null)

Answer (score 0):

You couldn't inject the sessionFactory to studentDAO calss. Check on it